# Getting error was caught where a drag was occuring with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-beautiful-dnd

Im using react-beautiful-dnd 13.0.0, And I've implemented the onDragEnd functionalities, it was working fine but now I'm facing this issue when dragging a card to another table (it works fine in its own table) it stops and shows that error :

> react-beautiful-dnd
> An error was caught by our window 'error' event listener while a drag was occurring. The active drag has been aborted.
> ‍ This is a development only message. It will be removed in production builds

If someone faced the same issue or could solve, it will be great thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you by any chance figured out what's wrong? I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: @Domagoj Vuković - have the same, did you guys find out what's wrong?

Comment: Uh, this was a long time ago, I don't remember. I think found something on beautiful dnd GitHub, try searching there.